# Concise yet scalable Scala/sbt testing to verify Project Euler answers

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, scalatest

I’m using [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) to learn functional programming in Scala, along with sbt and other best practices. My initial stab at creating tests to verify solutions using [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) was:

```
package euler
import org.scalatest._

class SolutionsSpec extends Spec with Matchers {
    "The problems" should "have the correct solutions" in {
        Problem1.solve should be (  233168 )
        Problem2.solve should be ( 4613732 )
        Problem3.solve should be (    6857 )
        Problem4.solve should be (  906609 )
    }
}
```

This is concise, but I’m afraid it might not scale if I ever get to harder problems with longer run times. As far as I can tell, I can't test individual problems this way.

I have searched on GitHub and found two helpful examples, similar to what I am trying to do:

- [danielmiladinov/ProjectEuler-Scala](https://github.com/danielmiladinov/ProjectEuler-Scala/tree/master/src/test/scala/euler)
- [todd-cook/Effective-Scala-with-Project-Euler](https://github.com/todd-cook/Effective-Scala-with-Project-Euler/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/cookconsulting/projecteuler/ProblemVerifierTest.scala)

Both are more verbose than I would like, since I’m basically just testing a mapping from problem number to solutions.

**My question**: Is there a concise and elegant way to do this testing that is still flexible so that I can check the result for a single or group of problems?

**Edit**: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123857/1991333) discouraging TDD with Project Euler. To clarify, I am writing unit tests for math helper functions as well. My purpose for checking the answers is partly to check for regressions, but most important as an exercise.

**Edit 2**: I am now trying to use [FunSuite](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.0/index.html#org.scalatest.FunSuite):

```
class SolutionsSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {
    test("Problem 1") { Problem1.solve should be (  233168 ) }
    test("Problem 2") { Problem2.solve should be ( 4613732 ) }
    test("Problem 3") { Problem3.solve should be (    6857 ) }
    test("Problem 4") { Problem4.solve should be (  906609 ) }
}
```

This might be closer to what I want. The output looks better:

```
$ sbt test
...
[info] SolutionsSuite:
[info] - Problem 1 (28 milliseconds)
[info] - Problem 2 (4 milliseconds)
[info] - Problem 3 (38 milliseconds)
[info] - Problem 4 (172 milliseconds)
```

But I have still not been able to figure out how to run a subset of the problems. This question seems to indicate that what I am looking for is not yet possible with sbt: [Run just a specific scalatest test from sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205484/run-just-a-specific-scalatest-test-from-sbt).

**Edit 3**: It looks like the ability to run single test function as opposed to an entire suite is targeted for sbt 0.13.3 per issue [Allow running of single junit test #911](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/911).

**Edit 4**: For reference, [my Project Euler GitHub project](https://github.com/esturcke/euler-scala).

Answer (score 2):

You might like to copy my setup at https://github.com/sethtisue/project-euler . Each test looks like:

```
class Problem1 extends Problem(1, "12345") {
  def solve: Int = ...
}
```

Where the "12345" is the expected answer (always a string), and the return type of `solve` can be anything (since it's just going to get `.toString`ed, since a string is what you're going to end up entering at the Euler site).

`Problem` is defined such that each problem is its own suite, so you can easily use sbt's `test-only` command to run just the problems you want.

Comment: Interesting to think of the problem solvers as tests rather than putting them in `main`. That way you can encapsulate each solution, but don’t need excessive duplicate code just to check the answers. Also, thanks for the tip of using parameters with the `Problem` trait.